# Clean url for SEO in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

How to remove the controller/method for cleaner URL in codeIgniter.

The original url is below

```
www.mydomain.com/controllers/method/variable
```

and I want my url look like this

```
www.mydomain.com/variable
```

or

```
www.mydomain.com/friendly-url-description/5
```

where `5` is key or id of the table, and the friendly-url-description is description of the value. please help guys.

Comment: Why do you think that this will have more of a benefit to search engines? There is no proof to suggest that such a minute change would effect search engine metrics enough to help you rank better in Google. However, it is a far better change for your users as the URL they will see will be shorter and easier to remember.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to modify the file `/system/application/config/routes.php` like for instance:

```
<?php
$route['friendly-url-description/(:any).html'] = 'controllers/method/$1';
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: using (:any) is a double edged sword. it would be wiser to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CodeIgniter Routing.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Try using regular expressions, for this one:

```
www.mydomain.com/controllers/method/variable

www.mydomain.com/variable
```

try using if it's just string:

```
$route['(a-zA-Z)'] = 'controllers/method/$1';
```

for this one:

```
www.mydomain.com/friendly-url-description/5
```

try using:

```
$route['(a-zA-Z)/(0-9)'] = 'controllers/method/$1/$2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **URI Routing**.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess you can rewrite the url to whatever you like.

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(\w+)& controllers/method/$1
```

I haven't tested that, but it should make the address www.mypage.com/var referr to www.mypage.com/controllers/method/var

The shorthand "\w" means "any character or number", that is a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore. The + means "once or more". Look up a regular expression tutorial to learn more.

Good luck :)

Comment: I tried but it will not work. 
I'm using codeigniter framework.

this is the original link.
www.mydomain.com/controllers/method/variable
and I want like this
www.mydomain.com/variable.

look like this.
www.mydomain.com/clean-url-for-seo-in-codeigniter/id